# Best way to safely printf to a string?

Tags: c++, stl

Does anyone know a good safe way to redirect the output of a printf-style function to a string? The obvious ways result in buffer overflows.

Something like:

```
string s;
output.beginRedirect( s );  // redirect output to s

... output.print( "%s%d", foo, bar );

output.endRedirect();
```

I think the problem is the same as asking, "how many characters will print produce?"
Ideas?

Comment: Just `size_t nbytes = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s", name) + 1; /* +1 for the '\0' */
char *str = malloc(nbytes);
snprintf(str, nbytes, "%s", name);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738/c-how-to-get-fprintf-results-as-a-stdstring-w-o-sprintf#69911) has a similar discussion.  Also in that question I present my favorite solution, a "format" function that takes identical arguments to printf and returns a std::string.

Answer (score 30):

You can use:

[`std::snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) if you are working with a char*

[`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) if you want to use strings (not same as printf but will allow you to easily manipulate the string using the normal stream functions).

[`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) if you want a function similar to printf that will work with streams. (as per jalf in comments)

[`fmt::format`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which is has been standardized since c++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)

Comment: and boost::format to get printf-like formatting capabilities with C++ streams

Comment: You can use `std::snprintf` if you are working with `wchar_t*` too, so long as you use `mbstowcs_s` to allocate the converted buffer.

Answer (score 11):

The `snprintf()` function prints to a string, but only as much as the length given to it.

Might be what you're looking for...

Comment: Faster than me. This is the old school way to do it.

Comment: You can use sprintf that does not require a length.  Also this will not work with strings as he asked...

Comment: @abyx - spot on! It'd be good to add an example for std::string, e.g. snprintf(target, SIZE, "%s%d", foo.c_str(), bar);

Comment: @Adam - sprintf is unsafe, and it's exactly what the poster asked how to avoid

Answer (score 9):

[The {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) provides a safe `printf` implementation. For example, `fmt::sprintf` formats and returns a `std::string`:

```cpp
std::string s = fmt::sprintf("%s%d", foo, bar);
```

If you are OK with a slightly different format string syntax you could also use C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format):

```cpp
std::string s = std::format("{}{}", foo, bar);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 std::format.

Answer (score 5):

Since you've tagged this as C++ (rather than just C), I'll point out that the typical way to do this sort of thing in C++ is to use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/), not the printf family.  No need to worry about buffer overflows with stringstreams.

The [Boost Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/format/index.html) library is also available if you like printf-style format strings but want something safer.

Comment: +1 for Boost Format (beat me to it :)

Answer (score 5):

snprintf() returns the number of bytes needed to write the whole string.
So, as a tiny example:

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char* buf = 0;
    size_t bufsize = 0;
    size_t sz;

    const char* format="%s and %s.";
    const char* str_1 ="string 1";
    const char* str_2 ="string 2";

    sz = snprintf(buf, bufsize, format, str_1, str_2);
    printf("The buffer needs to be %d bytes.\n", sz);

    buf=malloc(sz+1);
    if(!buf) {
        printf("Can't allocate buffer!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    bufsize = sz+1;
    buf[bufsize-1] = '\0';
    sz = snprintf(buf, bufsize, format, str_1, str_2);
    printf("Filled buffer with %d bytes.\n", sz);
    printf("The buffer contains:\n'%s'\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
The buffer needs to be 22 bytes.
Filled buffer with 22 bytes.
The buffer contains:
'string 1 and string 2.'
```

Answer (score 4):

Old school:

```
snprintf()
```

allows you to put a limit on the number written, and return the actual written size, and

```
asprintf()
```

allocate (with `malloc()`) a sufficient buffer which then becomes your problem to `free()`. `asprintf is a GNU libc function now reimplemented in the BSD libc.

Answer (score 1):

With C99 you have the snprintf-function which takes the size of the buffer as a parameter.  The GNU C-library has asprintf which allocates a buffer for you.  For c++ though, you might be better of using iostream.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Buffer_safety_and_sprintf) has more info.

Answer (score 1):

I find the printf formatting to be very helpful and easier to use than streams. On the other hand, I do like std::string a lot too. The solution is to use sprintf, but that cannot handle arbitrary buffer size.

I've found that I need to handle common case (say, buffer limited to 256 chars) w/o 
overhead, and yet handle the large buffer safely. To do that, I have a buffer of 256 chars alocated in my class as a member, and I use snprinf, passing  that buffer and its size. If snprintf succeeds, I can immediately retunr the formatted string. If it fails, I allocate the buffer and call snprinf again. The buffer is deallocated in the class' destructor.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows:

```
StringCchPrintf
StringCbPrintf
```

from `strsafe.h/lib`.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft introduce the '[safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/239ffwa0(VS.80).aspx)' crt functions for this.

You could use [printf_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/239ffwa0(VS.80).aspx)()

Comment: Not available on any other standards conforming implementation, so yuck.

Comment: Also, the only difference is that the "safe" crt will crash themselves if they detect certain undefined behaviors. That doesn't bypass the issue he's encountering.