# What is the point of using va_copy?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I read a little about variadic functions in C/C++ and I found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627731) that mentions to reuse a va_list in GCC you need to use a copy of it with va_copy and on the same thread they have suggested defining it with

`#define va_copy(d,s) ((d) = (s))` 
Which means that it is simply assigning the value of va_list s to va_list d.

Wouldn't it be more readable to use `va_list ap1 = va_list ap` instead? What is the point of creating another function called va_copy?

Comment: The answer in that thread that suggests defining it as `((d) = (s))` does **not** suggest doing that for GCC or generally. It is a **specific** suggestion for MSVC. The C standard defines certain properties that `va_copy` and related features must satisfy, and C implementations accomplish those in different ways. In MSVC’s method of supporting variable argument lists, `((d) = (s))` may work. In others, it likely does not.

Answer (score 10):

> in GCC you need to use a copy of it with va_copy and on the same thread they have suggested defining it with
>
> `#define va_copy(d,s) ((d) = (s))` Which means that it is simply assigning the value of va_list s to va_list d.

That's not what they are saying in the other thread.  In the [J Jorgenson answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627731/4342498) they state:

> When attempting to reuse a va_list on GCC, one MUST use va_copy(), as the GCC implementation causes the va_list to be modified, causing the pointer to be positioned after last param after use by a v??printf() function.

Which means if you need to make a copy in GCC, you need to use `va_copy`

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2289581/4342498) that talks about implementing `va_copy` as

> A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558223/va-copy-porting-to-visual-c) about the lack of va_copy in MSVC had some decent enough suggestions, including to implement your own version of va_copy for use in MSVC:
>
> ```
> #define va_copy(d,s) ((d) = (s))
> ```

Is talking about MSVC which does not implement `va_copy`.  The reason you would add such a "usless" macro is so that you can just use `va_copy` and get the correct behavior in both GCC and MSVC.

> Wouldn't it be more readable to use va_list ap1 = va_list ap instead? What is the point of creating another function called va_copy?

Depending on how `va_list` is implemented it might not be "enough" to just do `va_list ap1 = va_list ap`.  There can be thing that need to happen that can't be done with `operator =`.  For instance, if `va_list` is a pointer type, you can't overload `operator =` for it so you need to make a named "function".

Comment: Though the wording may not imply, I am aware of this. What I question about is why not simply tell everyone to use `va_list ap1 = ap` which should do the same thing in a more intuitive way.

Comment: @R3G3N3R4T0R I've added to the answer about that.

Comment: @R3G3N3R4T0R because you can't copy a `va_list` like that in most compilers, copying is implementation-defined and that kind of assignment is not portable. `va_copy()` is more portable, except for MSVC, where such direct assignment happens to be supported