# Building Mesa 3d 7.10 with llvmpipe on MSVC10

Tags: opengl, build, visual-studio-2010, mesa

Has anybody successfully build Mesa 7.10 with llvmpipe driver using LLVM 2.8 on Windows with the Visual Studio 2010 toolchain?

The official release files contain no SConscript, so I got the 7.10 branch from their git repository and tried to build it. I get weird link errors about __fopen, __exit and other standard libraries.

**Update**:
Got the problem. Both had to compile with the same runtime libraries, but LLVM was compiled with MD and Mesa with MT. So I switched both to MT. But still have a problem - it gives me a link error about __va_copy. I can see it is called from the Mesa code, and the code compiles properly but DOES NOT LINK. I don't understand why :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

va_copy is not provided by all compilers. You might get away with adding a simple #define macro in the mesa code. See [va_copy -- porting to visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/558223/635608) for a discussion about va_copy.